# Alternative To With Math In Javascript

Tags: javascript

I put my Javascript code through an analyzer and was told not to use `with (Math)`. I can't figure out an alternative way to make this work. Any ideas? The code makes both a regular clock and an octal clock. I'll post the code now:

```
var oct = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"];
var c;
var now;
var day;
var month;
var year;
var octtime;
var oct1;
var oct2;
var oct3;
var oct4;
var oct5;
var oct6;
var octvalue;
var point = ".";
function a() {
  c = checkTime;
  now = new Date();
  day = now.getDate();
  month = now.getMonth();
  year = now.getFullYear();
  var hours = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds();
  var totsecs = hours * 3600;
  totsecs += minutes * 60;
  totsecs += seconds;
  totsecs += (now.getTime() % 1000) / 1000;
  hours = c(hours);
  minutes = c(minutes);
  seconds = c(seconds);
  with (Math) {
    octtime = floor(totsecs / (86400 / 262144))
    oct1 = floor(octtime / 32768)
    octtime -= 32768 * oct1
    oct2 = floor(octtime / 4096)
    octtime -= 4096 * oct2
    oct3 = floor(octtime / 512)
    octtime -= 512 * oct3
    oct4 = floor(octtime / 64)
    octtime -= 64 * oct4
    oct5 = floor(octtime / 8)
    octtime -= 8 * oct5
    oct6 = octtime
  }
  octvalue = point + oct[oct1] + oct[oct2] + oct[oct3] + oct[oct4] + oct[oct5] + oct[oct6]
  document.getElementById('a').innerHTML=hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
  document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = octvalue
  timerID = setTimeout("a()")
  function checkTime(i)
  {
    if (i<10)
    {
      i="0" + i;
    }
    return i;
  }
}
window.onload = a;
```

Comment: Your code frightened me...

Comment: Looks a lot like a homework assignment that is meant to teach how to make a flooring algorithm / function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply prefix all your call to `floor` with `Math`.

Change

```
with (Math) {
octtime = floor(totsecs / (86400 / 262144))
```

to

```
octtime = Math.floor(totsecs / (86400 / 262144))
```

And yes, you must remove those `with`, the code analyzer is right. It's a bad practice, is illegal in strict code, and prevents function optimization by the JavaScript engine. See [the MDN on with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Note that there are details begging for a refactoring in your code. For example when you have variables named `oct1`... `oct8`, it's probable you could make that simpler and dryer with an array. Your variables should also no be all global, you can and should define some variables in the scope of the function.

If you feel it hard to deal with time formatting, then maybe you should have a look at a library like moment.js.

And of course, a properly indented code is easier to read and maintain...